# How does google elegantizr work?

Tags: css

So I was browsing through google's april fool's jokes, and I found this one

http://www.google.com/landing/elegantizr/

Which claims to load super fast css, but does this instead

http://shodor.org/~amalani/elegantizr.html

using this code

```
:before {
  content: '\41\50\52\49\4C\20\46\4F\4F\4C\20\F4\BF\F4';
}
```

What format is this, and how does it work?

Comment: Also, thanks for posting this.  I hadn't seen it yet and got a real kick out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content property specifies content to insert into your html.  It must be paired with either the :before or :after selector in order to specify where that content would be inserted.  Intended use is that the before or after selector is applied to an element.  For example:

```
.copyright:before {content: "\00A9 ";}
```

Would add a copyright symbol to the front of every element with the class "copyright".  CSS has it's own way of doing what in HTML are character entities.  More info can be found @ [css-tricks.com/css-content/](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/).  This is where I learned most of what I know about it.

In this case, though, they did not specify which element to apply this to, therefor, it is applied to all elements.

So the character codes used in the elegantizer are as follows:

```
\41 = A
\50 = P
\52 = R
\49 = I
\4C = L
\20 = space
\46 = F
\4F = O
\4F = O
\4C = L
\20 = S
\F4 = ô
\BF = ¿
\F4 = ô
```

A full list of unicode characters can be found at the [List of Unicode Characters Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters).  Simply remove the leading zeros and precede them with a backslash.